# Set Content root pah to a dotnet core app (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm starting my ASP.NET Core API using a script from a different directory (not dll's directory)

The problem is that the default Content root path is the script's directory.

How can I change it to the dll's directory?

It only works when starting the script from the dll's directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fixed 2 ways :

1 - Is from the Program.cs

You can HARD CODE the content root in Program.cs to mach the dll's directory :

```cs
public Static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        ...
        .UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        ...
}
```

2 - Set it as a environment variable

variable name : {PREFIX_}CONTENTROOT ( PREFIX is either DOTNET or ASPNETCORE )

```bash
export ASPNETCORE_CONTENTROOT=$HOME/myapi
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - my .NET 8 application is started by another application, so the current working directory wasn't my application's start up folder.  To fix it, I used:

```
WebApplicationOptions options = new() { 
  ContentRootPath = Application.StartupPath
}; 
WebApplicationBuilder webAppBuilder = webApplication.CreateBuilder(options);
```